# How do we handle merge issues with pull requests

Tags: git

I'm trying to understand how best to handle merge situations with pull requests.

We base all features of the master branch. We then create a release branch that we run PR's against.

The situation I don't know how to solve is when we PR first feature 1, then feature 2 into the release branch.

Feature 3 has a merge conflict with feature 1, so from what I've read we then need to manually merge release into feature 3 branch, then do a new PR from feature 3 to release branch.

If then, after having tested the release branch, we find that feature 1 and feature 2 is not going to be deployed, but we want to release feature 3. This is now not possible because both of those features are merged into the feature 3.

The best solution I've come up with so far is to make a "feature 3 - merge release" branch, but I'm not very happy with that solution. How should I handle situations like this?

(last time this happened btw, it was feature 1- 241 that we didn't need in the release)

Comment: If both features 1 and 2 have merge commits into feature 3, which are all merged into the release branch, what's wrong with simply reverting features 1 and 2? The act of reverting also documents the fact you don't want those features in your next release.

Comment: First of I didn't know you could revert a feature, last time i checked I had to revert the commits from feature 1 and feature 2. This is hard to do since there isn't anything that tells me what commits belong to what feature

Comment: You branch from `master`, but merge into `release`. How does `master` get updated?

Comment: pr from release to master after release is approved, then we push master into production, and a new release is created for the next release

Comment: @devzero So "release" is really "staging" or "QA"? Since `master`, `release`, and `production` will ultimately share the same history, it might be simpler to have just `master` and use tags to track where QA and production are.

Comment: @Schwern more or less, production is not a branch, but rather our prod environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's map this out. You have three feature branches. Here they're all branched from the same commit, but it doesn't matter.

```
      G - H [feature2]
     /
A - B - C [release]
    |\
    | I - J [feature1]
    \
     E - F [feature3]
```

You can see this sort of visualization with `git log --graph --decorate --oneline`, except it will go from top to bottom.

> *The situation I don't know how to solve is when we PR first feature 1, then feature 2 into the release branch.*

That leaves you like so.

```
      G - H ---
     /         \
A - B - C - K - L [release]
    |\     / 
    | I - J
    \
     E - F [feature3]
```

> *Feature 3 has a merge conflict with feature 1, so from what I've read we then need to manually merge release into feature 3 branch, then do a new PR from feature 3 to release branch.*

That leaves you like so.

```
      G - H ---
     /         \
A - B - C - K - L [release]
    |\     /     \
    | I - J       \
    \              \
     E - F -------- M [feature3]
```

> *If then, after having tested the release branch, we find that feature 1 and feature 2 is not going to be deployed, but we want to release feature 3. This is now not possible because both of those features are merged into the feature 3.*

A "branch" is just label on commits. You can move them around. This includes moving them to before the merge happened. First, re-establish `feature1` and `feature2` before they merged.

```
git branch feature1 J
git branch feature2 H

           [feature2]
      G - H ---
     /         \
A - B - C - K - L [release]
    |\     /     \
    | I - J [feature1]
    \              \
     E - F -------- M [feature3]
```

Then move `feature3` back before it merged.

```
git checkout feature3
git rest --hard F

           [feature2]
      G - H ---
     /         \
A - B - C - K - L [release]
    |\     / 
    | I - J [feature1]
    \ 
     E - F [feature3]
```

Then move `release` back before `feature1` and `feature2` were merged.

```
           [feature2]
      G - H
     /
A - B - C [release]
    |\
    | I - J [feature1]
    \ 
     E - F [feature3]
```

Now you're back before any merges happened. You can now merge `feature3` into `release`.

Comment: This will probably work fine...but it seems unnecessary complicated. Imagine that instead of 3 features, you have 20, 10 of which needed merging, 6 of witch you want to discard after testing. Re-establishing the original branches would be a lot of work.

Comment: @devzero If you're in that situation regularly, something is very wrong with your process. 20 features in flight indicates your project is probably too monolithic; consider breaking it up into services and libraries. 10 features awaiting merge again indicate too monolithic, and your review/merge process is too slow. Needing to discard 6 features at the same time *after* merging and testing indicates there's something wrong with your requirements process. Consider continuous integration instead. I can't say more without more detail, if you post a question about improving your process LMK.

Comment: I've maybee got 5-6 developers, each implementing 3-4 features (this is with weekly sprints). That's easily 20 branches I need to integrate. Using merge this is easy, create release branch, merge all 20 other branches into the release branch, If any of the 20 are rejected, delete the release branch and create a new release branch from the approved branches. With pull requests this is a nightmare because I have to roll back all merged branches before redoing the process. I'm obviously missing something, but I can't quite see what from your answers

Comment: @devzero You shouldn't be having those problems with that few developers and features. I have my suspicions why, but I'd need more detail to help. Particularly why you're regularly rejecting agreed upon and merged features. If you post a question about your development process and the problems you're having I'll be happy to give it a look. Just put a link to it here.